# Does a 3D Cursor equivalent exist for weight paint?

Tags: weight-painting

It would be useful to click in the same area with precision relative to a particular mesh.  It would be useful to simulate a paint click with a keystroke, with the center of the brush at the 3D Cursor.  I looked in the info window for the action of clicking and I do not see any info.  Of course I can select vertices and execute small steps, yet this is time consuming.

Thanks.